# warning after overwriting get_form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In my ClassBased Update/Create Views I added some classes:

```
class IndexUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = '__all__'
    model = Index
    template_name = 'index_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('IndexList')

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(IndexUpdateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['year'].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control tosp"})
        form.fields['index'].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control tosp"})
        return form
```

After adding the "get_form" I got the warning:

> RemovedInDjango110Warning: `Index.views.IndexCreateView.get_form` method must define a default value for its `form_class` argument.

How to define a default value?

Answer (score 12):

The `form_class` argument has been optional since Django 1.8 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#generic-views)). The warning is telling you that you must specify a default argument for form_class, e.g.

```
def get_form(self, form_class=MyFormClass):
    ...
```

If you look at the [default implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/11af73eaeb4371ded68460c1591abd6aefa57a90/django/views/generic/edit.py#L39), it uses `None` as the default, and calls `self.get_form_class()` when it isn't specified. Since you already call super() in your `get_form` method, you should be able to use `None` as the default as well.

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super(IndexUpdateView, self).get_form(form_class)
    ...
```

In your specific case, you could define a model form that changes the widget attrs in the `__init__` method. Then you won't have to override `get_form` at all.

```
class IndexForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IndexForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['year'].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control tosp"})
        self.fields['index'].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control tosp"})

class IndexUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = '__all__'
    model = Index
    form_class = IndexForm
    template_name = 'index_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('IndexList')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the property `form_class` to your class.

```
class IndexCreateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = MyFormClass
```

Comment: at the moment I don't have a FormClass. But I think I will add one :)
thanks

Comment: This will only stop the warning if you remove the `get_form` method and set the `form_class` attribute instead. If you keep the `get_form` method`, then you must set a default as in my answer.

Comment: Your answer was helpful anyway -- I hadn't noticed that creating a model form class might be better than changing `get_form`.